RE2 or Go Regex to match all ccTLD emails except for .us or .co
How can I create a filter for all ccTLD email addresses except for the ones that end with .co or .us using the Go RE2 regexp syntax?
I am trying to send all emails originating from a ccTLD to our quarantine to avoid SPAM and malware, but we don't want to quarantine .co or .us addresses because they are not typically used by adversaries.
I've attempted to use the following regex pattern, but it is invalid RE2:
^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.(?!us|co)[a-zA-Z]{2,}$

Edit: I'm updating to clarify, but my question was downvoted without much to go on. But the Go Regex (or RE2) is configured to match on the sender header. I'm looking to match all ccTLDs such as spam@domain.de, or fake@email.in, except for .us and .co.
The reason for this is because I have found a trend in all of the SPAM email that we receive where 95% of the SPAM comes from a ccTLD (I think because there are fewer restrictions for reporting abuse)
I don't care about what comes before the @, just after.
This is a challenging question, I am aware of this fact, but please provide a basis if you downvote the question to help.

Does your input consist of only Email addresses, or is it mixed content? If the former, you don't need such a complex pattern to check for an Email address format, just check the end of it.

"This is a challenging question": please note that the downvotes have nothing to do with some difficulty, but with the unclear specifications. Don't react to downvotes in your question. It will attract more of them. Just make sure to be very clear about the logic you need, by adding more examples of what should match and what should not match.  For instance, in a comment to a now deleted answer you said you wanted to only match 2-letter TLDs. This is nowhere mentioned in your question and doesn't follow from your attempted regex.

I found the answer thanks to another user's comment, which has since been deleted.
/^.+@.+\.(u[a-rt-z]|c[a-np-z]|[abd-t-vz][a-z])$/gmi

Matches:

bad@email.jp
List item
List item
really@bad.cn
not@trusted.ru
block@domain.com.jp
another@example.cn.cn
phake@email.ai
sure@bet-jp.jp

Non-Matches:

first.l@some-st.com
known@good.com
test@gmail.com
also@good.co
good@email.us
heres@another.mil
No-Reply@ci.city.st.us

